# Callable Firebase Cloud Function with region is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call an already successful deployed Firebase Cloud Function from my Vue.js application. The function needs to run from the `europe-west3` region.

I have a button that is clicked and then runs the `call()` method:

```
<script>
import { functions } from '@/firebase'
export default {
  methods: {
    call() {
      const callFunction = functions('europe-west3').httpsCallable('orgNew') // Error points to this line of code
      callFunction( { name: 'John Doe'}).then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I get these errors in the console:
[image: Errors in console]

In my `firebase.js` file I imported `Firebase` and created some helpers:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/functions'

let firebaseConfig = { // API KEYS AND CONFIG };
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

var db = firebase.firestore()
const auth = firebase.auth()
const functions = firebase.functions()

export {
  db,
  auth,
  functions
}
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: That error message doesn't look like it has anything to do with the code here.

Comment: @DougStevenson When opening the error message in the dev tools it exactly points to the line of code in my question (check updated code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has exported `firebase.functions()` from firebase.js.  It is not a function, but your importing code is calling it like a function.  That's what the error message is saying you're doing wrong.

Instead of exporting `firebase.functions()`, just export `firebase.functions`, which is a function you can use to initialize with a region.

Either that, or export `firebase.functions("europe-west3")`, use it in the importing code as `functions.httpsCallable()`.

Note that you currently have a typo in your region string.

Comment: Fixed the typo. In firebase.js I changed the code to 'firebase.functions("europe-west3)' and called it like you said: 'const callFunctionfunctions.httpsCallable("orgNew")'. Now I get this error:
 TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.functions.httpsCallable is not a function

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated problem.  I suggest reviewing the documentation, making note of what version of the client SDK you're using with your bundler: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize

Comment: I am using the newest bundle version (currently firebase@8.1.2 released 3/12/2020). Therefore I checked on the right importing (that differs from v7). So this seems not to be the problem I think.

Comment: Yes, the main import changed in v8.